# PDF file not Open in Mobile Devices

Tags: web-services, security, web

i have a website which contains lots of PDF its work good at desktop but mean while mobile devices do not support PDF file. There is no PDF file open in mobile devices. Any one give me idea to solve this issue.

Comment: pdf files are opened natively with chrome on iphone and safari.

Comment: so how can i fix it?

Comment: where is the website?

Comment: here is the url kitabjee.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is CSS. Try loading the page an your browser but make the window size narrow (like a phone) so that the sidebar drops below the pdfs. you will not be able to click on the pdf icon. something is wrong with how you are presenting the links/icons.

Specifically the entire section with the links is overshadowed by the search form.

Comment: I have solved the problem through your guidance @Jonathan